# I tried to copy pine editor revision 0.1 code to revision version=5 there is error in few line

Tags: pine-script

I tried to copy pine editor revision 0.1 code to revision version=5 there is error in few line how can i recode it for version=5
specifically I am getting error in these line

"i1 = c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1])" & "bgcolor(ribm?bfrC:na, transp=50)"

```
study(title="Coral Trend Indicator [LazyBear]", shorttitle="CTI_LB", overlay=true)
src=close
sm =input(21, title="Smoothing Period")
cd = input(0.4, title="Constant D")
ebc=input(false, title="Color Bars")
ribm=input(false, title="Ribbon Mode")
di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
c2 = 1 - c1
c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd
i1 = c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1])
i2 = c1*i1 + c2*nz(i2[1])
i3 = c1*i2 + c2*nz(i3[1])
i4 = c1*i3 + c2*nz(i4[1])
i5 = c1*i4 + c2*nz(i5[1])
i6 = c1*i5 + c2*nz(i6[1])

bfr = -cd*cd*cd*i6 + c3*(i5) + c4*(i4) + c5*(i3)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// For the Pinescript coders: Determining trend based on the mintick step. 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//bfrC = bfr - nz(bfr[1]) > syminfo.mintick ? green : bfr - nz(bfr[1]) < syminfo.mintick ? red : blue
bfrC = bfr > nz(bfr[1]) ? green : bfr < nz(bfr[1])  ? red : blue
tc=ebc?gray:bfrC
plot(ribm?na:bfr, title="Trend", linewidth=3, style=circles, color=tc)
bgcolor(ribm?bfrC:na, transp=50)
barcolor(ebc?bfrC:na)
```

```
study(title="Coral Trend Indicator [LazyBear]", shorttitle="CTI_LB", overlay=true)
src=close
sm =input(21, title="Smoothing Period")
cd = input(0.4, title="Constant D")
ebc=input(false, title="Color Bars")
ribm=input(false, title="Ribbon Mode")
di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
c2 = 1 - c1
c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd
i1 = c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1])
i2 = c1*i1 + c2*nz(i2[1])
i3 = c1*i2 + c2*nz(i3[1])
i4 = c1*i3 + c2*nz(i4[1])
i5 = c1*i4 + c2*nz(i5[1])
i6 = c1*i5 + c2*nz(i6[1])

bfr = -cd*cd*cd*i6 + c3*(i5) + c4*(i4) + c5*(i3)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// For the Pinescript coders: Determining trend based on the mintick step. 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//bfrC = bfr - nz(bfr[1]) > syminfo.mintick ? green : bfr - nz(bfr[1]) < syminfo.mintick ? red : blue
bfrC = bfr > nz(bfr[1]) ? green : bfr < nz(bfr[1])  ? red : blue
tc=ebc?gray:bfrC
plot(ribm?na:bfr, title="Trend", linewidth=3, style=circles, color=tc)
bgcolor(ribm?bfrC:na, transp=50)
barcolor(ebc?bfrC:na)
```

only two line I am getting error how can I resole it.

> i1 = c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1]) error is in bold letter nz(**i1**[1])  **i1**

bgcolor(ribm?bfrC:na, transp=50)

Answer (score 0):

For v3 [Self-referenced variables are removed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/appendix/Pine_version_3_migration_guide.html#self-referenced-variables-are-removed)

First you must initialize the values of i1, i2, i3, etc.

```
//@version=3
study(title="Coral Trend Indicator [LazyBear]", shorttitle="CTI_LB", overlay=true)

//<set initial values>
i1 = 0.0
i2 = 0.0
i3 = 0.0
i4 = 0.0
i5 = 0.0
i6 = 0.0

src=close
sm =input(21, title="Smoothing Period")
cd = input(0.4, title="Constant D")
ebc=input(false, title="Color Bars")
ribm=input(false, title="Ribbon Mode")
di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
c2 = 1 - c1
c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd
i1 := c1*src + c2*nz(i1[1])
i2 := c1*i1 + c2*nz(i2[1])
i3 := c1*i2 + c2*nz(i3[1])
i4 := c1*i3 + c2*nz(i4[1])
i5 := c1*i4 + c2*nz(i5[1])
i6 := c1*i5 + c2*nz(i6[1])

bfr = -cd*cd*cd*i6 + c3*(i5) + c4*(i4) + c5*(i3)
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// For the Pinescript coders: Determining trend based on the mintick step. 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
//bfrC = bfr - nz(bfr[1]) > syminfo.mintick ? green : bfr - nz(bfr[1]) < syminfo.mintick ? red : blue
bfrC = bfr > nz(bfr[1]) ? green : bfr < nz(bfr[1])  ? red : blue
tc=ebc?gray:bfrC
plot(ribm?na:bfr, title="Trend", linewidth=3, style=circles, color=tc)
bgcolor(ribm?bfrC:na, transp=50)
barcolor(ebc?bfrC:na)
```

Now you can convert it to v4, and v5
The Pine Script™ Editor includes a utility to automatically convert
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_5.html#v4-to-v5-converter

Comment: Pine Script convert is not working for these code.

Comment: Try again. I just used the same code and it works. I don't want to post v5. I want you to do it (and learn)

Comment: I am getting these error "Conversion failed, reason: Pine source is incorrect. line 14: Undeclared identifier 'i1';"

Comment: thank you for the migration guide. Some how i figured it out I tried like these i1 = 0.0
i2 = 0.0
i3 = 0.0
i4 = 0.0
i5 = 0.0
i6 = 0.0

i1 := c1 * src + c2 * nz(i1[1])
i2 := c1 * i1 + c2 * nz(i2[1])
i3 := c1 * i2 + c2 * nz(i3[1])
i4 := c1 * i3 + c2 * nz(i4[1])
i5 := c1 * i4 + c2 * nz(i5[1])
i6 := c1 * i5 + c2 * nz(i6[1])  Is there any short method, for knowledge purpose these will help.